# Hacer función que compruebe si una lista tiene 8 caracteres y dos numeros y si es cierto devuelva 2 y sino 0

Tags: python

No sé que he hecho mal. Y no entiendo lo de la nueva última función ya que esta es una respuesta que me ha pasado el profesor y aún así no funciona.

```
def validate(s): 

    if len(s) != 8: 
        return 0
    else: 
        counter = 0 
        for element in s: 
            if element in "0123456789": 
                counter = counter + 1 
                return counter == 2    
                counter = 0 
                for element in l: 
                    if validate(element): 
                        counter = counter + 1 
        return counter

def countChoose(s)
    counter = 0 
    for c in s: 
        if validate(element): 
            counter = counter + 1 
    return counter
```

Comment: por cierto alguien me podría añadir a discord o skype y hacerme un poco de profesor para resolverme dudas pls? es que estoy un poco perdido.

Comment: En python los espacios y tabulaciones **son muy importantes**. Por favor, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/230555/edit) tu pregunta y coloca el código **adecuadamente formateado**. Un espacio de mas o de menos puede hacer que tu código no funcione.

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia!

Comment: Respecto a tu petición de discord... ¿por qué no usas el [chat de Stack Overflow en Español](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El enunciado dice que tenga 8 caracteres y 2 números. Parece que has interpretado "8 caracteres en total, de los cuales 2 han de ser dígitos". Aunque también podría entenderse que con 8 caracteres quiso decir 8 letras. Entonces la cadena tendría una longitud 10 (8 letras y 2 números).

De momento me quedo con tu interpretación. Entonces:

> No sé que he hecho mal.

Pues analicemos tu función paso a paso:

```
def validate(s): 
    if len(s) != 8: 
        return 0
```

De momento empieza bien. `s` es la cadena a analizar, y si no tiene exactamente 8 letras ya no cumple una condición, así que retornas 0.

En otro caso:

```
    else: 
        counter = 0 
        for element in s: 
            if element in "0123456789": 
                counter = counter + 1 
                return counter == 2
```

Ibamos bien hasta el return. Tienes un contador, que empieza en cero. Para cada carácter en `s`, miras si es un dígito, y en ese caso le sumas 1 al contador **y retornas** un booleano que comprueba si `counter` es 2

Por tanto en el momento que encuentre el primer dígito, `counter` pasará a valer 1 y retornarás `False` (ya que `counter` es 1 y no 2).

Esto está mal por dos razones. Primero porque retornas antes de tiempo (no sabes si habrá más dígitos) y segundo porque retornas un booleano, cuando la función debía retornar 0 ó 2, pero nunca `True` o `False`.

Lo que sigue ya no tiene importancia, puesto que de todas formas ya has retornado. No llega por tanto a ejecutarse nunca. De todas formas, también estaba mal y no le veo el sentido:

```
                counter = 0 
                for element in l: 
                    if validate(element): 
                        counter = counter + 1
```

Vuelves a poner a cero el contador ¿por qué? Después iteras sobre otra variable `l` que en realidad ni siquiera existe. No te da error porque como he dicho nunca llega a ejecutarse esta parte. Y encima después llamas a `validate()` para cada elemento de `l`. `validate()` es la propia función que estás escribiendo, por lo que se estaría llamando a sí misma, pero en esta ocasión no le estás pasando una cadena, sino un elemento de `l` (no sé qué era lo que tenías en mente, pero esto no puede estar bien, ya que en esta llamada `len(elemento)` seguro que no será 8, por lo que la función retornará siempre `False`.

Al final retornas el contador. Si esa instrucción llegara a ejecutarse (lo que sólo ocurriría si no has encontrado dígitos en la cadena, pues si encuentras uno ya hemos visto que retornas inmediatamente), el contador valdría todavía cero, por lo que en ese caso retornarías cero.

No sé por qué has complicado tanto el bucle, que en principio iba bien. Bastaba que contaras cuántos dígitos había y, *después de haberlos contado* comprobaras si eran exactamente dos.

Es decir

```
def validate(s): 
    if len(s) != 8: 
        return 0
    else: 
        counter = 0 
        for element in s: 
            if element in "0123456789": 
                counter = counter + 1 
        if counter == 2:
            return 2
        else:
            return 0
```

En cuanto a la otra función que pones, no entiendo ni su cometido ni lo que preguntas.